# How to get integer value from ArrrayList<String> (this contains string as well as numbers)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, collections

```
public static int processData(ArrayList<String> array) 
   {
       ArrayList <Integer> no=new  ArrayList<Integer>();
       Iterator it=array.iterator();
        String[] strValues;
 while(it.hasNext())
           {
               strValues = array.toString().split(",");
               System.out.println(it.next());
               strValues = array.toString().split(",");
               no.add(0,strValues[2]);
               no.add(1,strValues[6]);
               strValues = array.toString().split(",");
              }          
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\dmo\\input.txt")));
            while(in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine().trim();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) // Ignore blank lines
                    inputData.add(line);
            }
            int retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\dmo\\output.txt")));
            output.println("" + retVal);
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Input text file contains records as 
20, AB CD ,55 ,876000
22, John carter, 57,987520 
23, abrahim ,55,5420130 
24,mariya , 55,8952403 
25,serena , 57,7895421

This data is passed as Arraylist  array to processData() function. I want to calculate avg salary of same department id. Eg. Avg of 55 de

Comment: is `987520 23` a *code* or a *number*? it has a space between.

Comment: input text contains                                                                                              20, AB CD ,55 ,876000
22, John carter, 57,987520
23, abrahim ,55,5420130
24,mariya , 55,8952403
25,serena , 57,7895421
first no is e-id, 2 is name,3rd is depart-id,4 is salary

Comment: @LKTN.25   it number ,its as 22,John carter, 57,987520 ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create String str_seperate="";  iterate array with regular exp. do str=array.remove(index);  and use Scanner sc=new Scanner(str).useDemiliter("\s*,\W\s*") to find out int and string data..

Answer (score 0):

Creating a person object on each line (assuming each line will have one person data) and adding them into a list. While calculating salary avg per department, first filtering out the persons for that department and then calculating total salary and then dividing by no of persons in that department. Hope it will help.

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int deptId;
    private double salary;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int id, String name, int deptId, double salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }

    public void setDeptId(int deptId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", deptId=" + deptId +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main {
    /*public static int processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
        ArrayList<Integer> no = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Iterator it = array.iterator();
        String[] strValues;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            strValues = array.toString().split(",");
            System.out.println(it.next());
            strValues = array.toString().split(",");
            no.add(0, strValues[2]);
            no.add(1, strValues[6]);
            strValues = array.toString().split(",");
        }
        return 1;
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine().trim();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) // Ignore blank lines
                    personList.add(getPerson(line));
            }
//            int retVal = processData(inputData);
//            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));
//            output.println("" + retVal);
//            output.close();

            double avgSalary = getAvgSalary(personList, 55);
            System.out.println(avgSalary);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Person getPerson(String str) {
        String[] strings = str.split(",");
        Person person = new Person(Integer.valueOf(strings[0].trim()), strings[1].trim(), Integer.valueOf(strings[2].trim()), Double.valueOf(strings[3].trim()));
        System.out.println(person);
        return person;
    }

    private static double getAvgSalary(List<Person> personList, int deptId) {
        List<Person> deptPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person : personList) {
            if (person.getDeptId() == deptId) {
                deptPersonList.add(person);
            }
        }

        double totalSalary = 0;
        for (Person person : personList) {
            totalSalary += person.getSalary();
        }

        return totalSalary / deptPersonList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: change input.txt file location as yours. I didn't get the use of output.txt, so commented it out. Hoping it will help.

Comment: nope... i have to read that text file. and i only allowded to make change in processData.. int processData(ArrayList<String> array) retuns string..          e.g. 20, AB CD ,55 ,876000, 22, John carter, 57,987520 ,23, abrahim ,55,5420130 ,24,mariya , 55,8952403, 25,serena , 57,7895421... then how to extract 55 ,876000 ,57,987520 etc. from string to caluculate avg of lowest dep-td from input...